# Migrate servers without losing any data / time-limited MySQL dump?

Tags: mysql, database, migration, dedicated-server

Is there a way to migrate from an old dedicated server to a new one without losing any data in-between - and with no downtime? In the past, I've had to lose MySQL data between the time when the new server goes up (i.e., all files transferred, system up and ready), and when I take the old server down (data still transferred to old until new one takes over). There is also a short period where both are down for DNS, etc., to refresh.

Is there a way for MySQL/root to easily transfer all data that was updated/inserted between a certain time frame?

Answer (score 3):

If you can run the servers in parallel, setup the old MySQL as a replication master, the new as a slave. Once the new server is running and sync'ed to the master, switch your DNS.

Comment: They're in different data centers, transferring to a different dedi host - would this still work? do you know of a better guide on this than http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/replication-howto.html ?

Comment: Yes this would work you will still need down time to make sure that there is no new data on the old server before you bring the new server to live or you could have duplicate content (ie primary keys). I did this and we managed to only have the site down for the prorogation time of dns

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication-howto.html is the latest for version 5.1.x